# How to force text condensation

Tags: typography, letterspacing

I have a title, that's written in font family with no condensed face. But I still want to bring letters closer to each other due to typographical reason.

I find couple of ways to change letterspacing:

1. Use a `soulutf8` package:

   ```
   \sodef\cond{}{.01em}{.01em}{.01em}
   ```
2. Use `fontenc` and redefine font parameters:

   ```
   \newfontfamily\headingfontcond[LetterSpace=.01]{MyFont-Bold}
   ```

Both of this ways works if letter space is greater than one. But if I try to make text narrower, but not wider, it just doesn't change anything.

BTW, I unable to use `microtype` package because I render text with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Did you try a negative value instead of a `.01`? But I doubt this is good typographic practice – condensed fonts are crafted especially for this, and they have a design that is very different from normal fonts in order to accommodate the shrinking. If it is for a title, why not use a font that has a condensed version? It is fine to use 2-3 different fonts in a document.

Comment: Condensing using a negative letter spacing is a very bad idea as the example in David's answer shows.

Comment: @egreg as I posted my answer I was in fear of a backlash from you :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LetterSpace` works also with negative values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Alegreya}
\newfontface{\titlingfont}[LetterSpace=-10]{Alegreya Bold}

\begin{document}
{\Large\titlingfont A HIDEOUS TITLE}

\Large\bfseries A HIDEOUS TITLE
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `\scalebox` from `graphicx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Alegreya}
\newfontface{\titlingfont}[LetterSpace=-10]{Alegreya Bold}

\begin{document}
{\Large\titlingfont A HIDEOUS TITLE\par}

\scalebox{0.85}[1]{\Large\bfseries A HIDEOUS TITLE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's so obvious, why I just even don't twig to use negative numbers? ) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The letter spacing is very bad typographical practice. I recommend to use slightly linear deformation in the wide.

The LaTeX was not specified as necessary in this question, so I use the plainTeX solution. Of course, XeTeX is used as you wish.

```
\input opmac

\def\titlefont{\typosize[20/25]\bf}

\def\narrowerto #1\hbox#2{\hbox{\pdfsave
   \pdfscale{#1}{1}\rlap{#2}\pdfrestore}}

\hbox{\titlefont This is text}
\bigskip
\narrowerto 0.95 \hbox{\titlefont This is text}

\end
```

You can try to run xetex document.

But if you exactly need to use this bad typographical practice then you can try the following code:

```
\input opmac

\def\letterspaced #1 #2{\def\tmpb{#2}%
   \replacestrings{ }{\ }\replacestrings{}{\kern#1}\tmpb}

\def\titlefont{\typosize[20/25]\bf}

{\titlefont \letterspaced -1pt {This is text}}

\end
```

You can try to run xetex document.

Comment: Just a short note that if `opmac` builds upon `plain.tex`, then `\narrower` is already defined.

Comment: @morbusg: you are right. The original Knuth's \narrower is blocked by the code above. If you need it then use another name.

Comment: The OP is using `soul` and `fontspec`, so Plain XeTeX is out of the question. But the attempt is good anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If it is just a one-off title, and you are sure you want to do this, just position it all manually (which you should do anyway if you are hand lettering a title)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\huge
       This

       T\hspace{-.09em}h\hspace{-.05em}i\hspace{-.06em}s

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use `\kern`? I thought it was made for such cases …

Comment: @Tobi 'cause I reprimanded someone on a question the other day for using TeX primitives in a latex document:-) (presumably there is no automatic line breaking in this title so it makes no difference, so why not use the latex syntax?)

Comment: So assuming the OP didn't reprimand anybody for using TeX primitives in a LaTeX document recently, the reason doesn't not apply to them? ;)

Comment: “so why not use the latex syntax?” hm … for me `\kern` feels right to kern letters ;-)